# How to disable inserting '*' at start of new line when formatting block comment in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, comments, code-formatting, eclipse-formatter

Original:

```
/* NOT THESE
private String deathPlace;
private String birthPlace;  
private LocalDate birthDate;    
private String notes;
*/
```

Unwanted result:

```
/*
* NOT THESE private String deathPlace; private String birthPlace; private
* LocalDate birthDate; private String notes;
*/
```

Is there a way of disabling '*' at start of new line? I guess its javadoc standard thing, but it gets annoying when i want to **uncomment**.

Comment: that's why I use ctrl+7 to comment and uncomment. It's really annoying to use /* */ blocks and there's no way to change the eclipse format the way you want, AFAIK. Except of course if you write a plugin just for it.

Comment: @shikida Very nice shortcut!

Comment: To comment out code, better use line comments `//` via the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+C. This makes it easier to comment in some lines but keep the rest commented out.

Comment: @howlger Thank you for help. It looks like same function as with ctrl+7.

Comment: Yes, it's the same. Sorry, I misread @shikida's comment. Even if you can disable formatting of block comments in the Java formatter, which would give you the desired result (no leading * and no removal of line breaks), line comments are recommended for commenting out code. Shikida, please add it as answer.